# Image Texture scaling

Tags: image, uv-image-editor, vector-mapping

After importing a .fbx sofa model I found online, I realized the scale was set to 0.001 so I applied the scale (Ctrl + A, S) to set it to 1 but my image texture is still far too big to display properly. I've tried scaling my image down through the mapping nodes but I can not get it to work. I checked the UV editor and the mesh on the sofa is so tiny that it's impossible to even see on my screen. How do I get this to scale properly? I've added a plane in the scene to demonstrate what the image texture should look like and how I normally apply my textures.

[image]

Here is a [link to the .blend file](https://estout-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/johng/ERYSC_K0t09LrXyRaL5T99IBYnR3i1xbwU_5wxnlTva50A?e=rn5bbI)

Comment: Does your object have a UV map? Can you add an image that shows it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are 2 UV maps ("*UV_Channel_1*" and "*...2*") but they are empty (or broken).
[image: empty UV maps]

To fix them **delete the UV maps** and **create new UV maps for all parts of the couch**.
With the mouse in the 3D viewport and in *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>U</kbd> for unwrap menu, then select "Smart UV Project" from the menu, and you will have a working UV map.

[image: new UV map example]

(The bottom part of the couch needs some manual adjustments in the UV editor or scaling.)

Last but not least:
In the render settings, under Color Management, **set View Transform to "*Filmic*"** to get a natural look of the light/exposure. You can set the **Look** to "***High contrast***" if you want to have richer colors.
(And of course, add some more lights to your scene ;-)

[image: color management]

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation! That all makes sense to me now.